# How to call onReceive() to reject calls?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I've managed to write the code to block incoming calls, but it's in a different class, and I want to execute it when a user presses "yes" on the dialog box. How do I call onReceive()? What intent do I pass  as the argument?

Here's the code of MainActivity -

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    activateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.activate);
    activateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                DialogBox();
        }
    });

}

protected void DialogBox() {
    box = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    box.setTitle("Reject incoming calls?").
            setMessage("On activation, your phone will reject all incoming calls").setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //BLOCK CALLS

                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog alert = box.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

And here's the class that extends BroadcastReceiver. onReceive holds the code to  reject the call.

```
public class RejectCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ITelephony telephonyService;
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String phoneNumber = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
        Log.d("INCOMING", phoneNumber);
        if ((phoneNumber != null)) {
            telephonyService.endCall();
            Log.d("HANG UP", phoneNumber);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Also, to perform an action as such, what permissions will I have to declare in AndroidManifest?

Note - I've gone through similar questions, but none of them seem to be calling onReceive(), hence the question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your broadcast receiver in the android manifest fileas follows.

```
<receiver android:name=".RejectCall">                     
            <intent-filter>                                                   
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>   
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Also, you will have to give the following permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Putting the above 2 pieces of code in your android manifest should trigger the `onRecieve()` of the reject call reciever.

Comment: Thanks, that answers a part of my question. But if you see my MainActivity class, I open up a dialog box, and I'd like to block calls only if the user presses yes in the dialog box. How would I do that? I somehow need to stitch onRecieve() with user pressing yes.